# Filling empty column value with 0 or Null in Python CSV writter

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am creating a CSV file in python and writing data using Django model and SQL server. I have a few null values in the database. when I write CSV file it writes nulls as ''(empty). how can I fill up the empty field in CSV with "Null" or "0"?

```
with open(f'{store_data}/test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as dataFile:
    task_data = MonitorItem.objects.all()
    wr = csv.writer(dataFile)
    # wr.writerow(taskHeaders)
    for t in task_data:
        wr.writerow([t.x, t.y, t.z])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
with open(f'{store_data}/test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as dataFile:
    task_data = MonitorItem.objects.all()
    wr = csv.writer(dataFile)
    # wr.writerow(taskHeaders)
    for t in task_data:
        x = t.x or "0"
        y = t.y or "0"
        z = t.z or "0"
        wr.writerow([x, y, z])
```

---

Here the **`x = t.x or "0"`** is queal to

```
if t.x:
    x = t.x
else:
    x = "0"
```

Hope this helps!!